# Alternative for Covariance for silverlight 4.0 IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, ienumerable, covariance

I am using silverlight 4.0 in my application. I have a method in my base class as mentioned below

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected CustomRequest GetCustomRequest(IEnumerable<IRequestType> types)
    {
        //Some code here...
    }
}
```

In my derived class when I call this method like below I get error

```
IEnumerable<RequestType> requestTypes = CodeToGetThis();
GetCustomRequest(requestTypes)
```

Note here that in calling statement the type of requestTypes is a enumerable of **derived type of IRequestType**.

This works well in desktop applications due to introduction of covariance in c#4.0. But it seems that for silverlight 4.0 it is not done for IEnumerable interface.

So what is the best alternative approach I should use in my silverlight application for this?

I somewhere read that it can be done using method overloading but not sure how to do this.

**UPDATE:**
One thing I missed in the first draft of the question is, I will have many derived types of IRequestType hence craeating overloaded method for each derived type will be a difficulty for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast each item to the interface e.g.

```
IEnumerable<IRequestType> requestTypes = CodeToGetThis().Select(x => (IRequestType)x);
GetCustomRequest(requestTypes)
```

You could do something with method overloading and have a method that took your derived/concrete type but you would only end up doing something like the above and calling the original method in the overload.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and this works.
Do you think this is better approach than overloading?

Comment: It depends, you will need to do this in your overloaded method anyway.  If overloading makes your code cleaner and you have lots of instances of calling this method then do it, if it is one or 2 then it is probably over kill.